# Blocking Rabbit Queue from accepting connections

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to block specific queue from been consumed for a specific time .
Is there a way to block access to Rabbit specific queue for some time ?
I don't control clients only Rabbit.

Answer (score 0):

not directly from RMQ

there are a few options, but may not be very good.

you could, for example, delete the queue. if there is no queue, it cannot be consumed. but this means you can't collect messages in that queue for later. you would also run into problems when consumers try to connect to the queue. they would either error, or would create the queue.

the same goes for the binding between the exchange and queue - you could delete it. but again, your queue won't collect messages while the binding is missing.

your best options, assuming you still need to collect the message and just delay processing of them, would be one of two things:

1) write code that sends the messages to a different queue, with no consumer attached to it. then after whatever period of time, re-publish those messages to the correct queue.

or

2) if you just need to delay each message individually, the delayed message exchange plugin will do that for you. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange

Comment: Thanks for the answer it surprise me that this simple flow is not supported by Rabbit.I submitted an issue https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/903.